# Need hours difference in SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, time

Looking for a query which can retrieve the time difference of two times. Below is the example:

```
EmpID   EmpOnTime   EmpOffTime
1       2:45        3:00
2       1:00        4:00
3       1:35        2:55
4       2:45        3:20
```

Result should be:

```
For EmpID 1 Time diffrence: 0:15
For EmpID 2 Time diffrence: 3:00
For EmpID 3 Time diffrence: 1:20
For EmpID 4 Time diffrence: 0:35
```

I am using the following query which giving wrong result
Query:

```
select offTime, onTime, (strftime('%s',offTime) - strftime('%s',onTime)) / 60 AS diffrence 
from emplyoee;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was trickier than initially thought.  Here is the SQL you will need, however your input data will need to be formatted differently to get it to work.

```
select EmpId, 
       offTime, 
       onTime, 
       time(((strftime('%s', offTime) - strftime('%s', onTime)) / 60), 'unixepoch') as difference
  from employee;
```

I had to store the data in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:

```
2019-07-18 03:00:00
```

Otherwise SQLite gets confused if you mean am or pm, and the %s cannot calculate since it returns the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
SELECT
  EmpID,
    time(
      julianday("2000-01-01 00:00:00") +
      julianday(substr("0" || EmpOffTime || ":00", 1, 8)) -
      julianday(substr("0" || EmpOnTime || ":00", 1, 8))) As diff
FROM 
  yourTable
```

**[[`SQL Fiddle Demo`]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2be29/67)**

Your times need to complete with `:00` at the end and sometimes with `0` at the beginning that I handle it with `substr("0" || yourTime || ":00", 1, 8)`, then by using `julianday()` you can find differences of two date, and also I add `julianday("2000-01-01 00:00:00")` to difference to get make a valid value of time and so on.

Comment: This giving the {null} values as Result